# JWT tokens in React JS, to lift the token state onto a container or store it in html storage?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, jwt, session-storage

I am creating my first site using React JS in the front end. The server side uses JWT to allow access to protected routes. In some examples, I see that the token is stored in a storage (localStorage or sessionStorage). Is it better to store the token as a state on the app container or in the html storage? What are the pros and cons of each method?

Comment: I think, token is stored in localStorage or sessionStorage to prevent its value from being lost on refresh. Component's state will be flushed out on refresh but values stored in localStorage will persist there.

Comment: @RiteshBansal I was thinking of creating a protected route wrapper component in react using react-router. So in that component, I would simply check if the token exists in the storage right? The app container doesn't really need store a state regarding the token.

Comment: Yes. I also follow the same kind of approach.